# How to call UIViewController::viewDidLoad from inside a static library on iOS?

Tags: ios

I want manually call `UIViewController::viewDidLoad` from inside a library but without having to hardcode the name of the main class.

I need this because I want to reuse the same library code in several iOS applications.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a solution but **I am still looking for a better one**.

inside AppController::viewDidLoad:

```
[Some setDelegate:self]; // to call again viewDidLoad
```

inside Some

```
[delegate viewDidLoad];
```